# Estimating the variance of error in empirical approximation to a distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables in $\mathbb{R}$ with common cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F(x)$.  The empirical approximation to $F(x)$ is defined as follows:

$$\hat{F}_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}(x)\tag{1}$$

where $\mathbf{1}_A(x)$ is an indicator function: unity when $x\in A$ and zero otherwise.

Per an answer to my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161222/what-is-known-about-the-distribution-of-the-errors-in-empirical-approximation-of), by [Donsker's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) the scaled error process $G_n(x)\equiv\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{F}_n(x)-F(x)\right)$ converges to the Brownian bridge process $B(F(x))$.

I am interested in the error of a point estimate $\hat{F}_n(x_0)$.  The first sentence of the "History" section of the [Wikipedia article on the Donsker's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) states the following:

> By the classical central limit theorem, for fixed $x$, the random variable $G_n(x)$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian (normal) random variable $G(x)$ with zero mean and variance $F(x)(1 − F(x))$ as the sample size $n$ grows.

I have two questions about this statement (in order of importance):

1. What is the standard approach when $F(x)$ is unknown?  Can one use the estimate $\hat{F}_n(x)$? (similarly to how
   we use the sample variance estimator to approximate the confidence
   interval for unknown mean given unknown variance)
2. While I am familiar with the standard proofs and the use of the
   classical CLT, I don't see how one proves the statement above using standard CLT.  Can
   someone provide a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only interested in estimating $F$ at a single point $x_0$, then you are really just estimating the probability $p_0 = \mathbb{P}\left(X\in (-\infty,x_0]\right)$.  The indicator variables $B_i = [X_i\leq x_0]$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli with (potentially unknown) probability $p_0$, so you can apply the usual CLT machinery to get the stated result and from there a confidence interval for $p_0$.

Similar methods work if you care about $F$ at finitely many points.  You only really need Donsker's Theorem to understand the whole process $G$ at once.

Comment: Aha -- the key word is "Bernoulli"!  I think I understand how this works now.  All this is new to me, and I appreciate your help.